# can i retrieve child entity containing parent entity id by using Spring Data Jpa one-to-many unidirectional relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Here is my parent entity:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    int parentId;
    String name;
    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    List<Child> childList;
}

public class Child {
    int childId;

    //if i am taking this property as non-transient application won't run. but i need parent Id without changing the class structure.. 
    @Transient
    int parentId;
    // ... some other properties
}
```

**Insertion is successful as two tables are created : parent(id,name),
child(id,name,parent_id).**

> But when I retrieve the Parent record then in the Child object, the
>   parentId property remains 0.

Comment: By choosing to annotate Transient, you are choosing not to store the relationship between parent and child in the database. You need to figure out why your application won't run. Using transient tag is wrong in this case. Why don't you post why your application isn't running? You are chasing the wrong problem.

Comment: In the above case my application is running but while retrieving the parent entity from db, the child entitiy does not contain "parentId" because of @Transient annotation. I don't want to retrieve the whole parent object inside my child object..
I just want to retrieve parentId.

Comment: Then you should use lazy loading. Even though it retrieves a parent object, only the id will be populated, the rest of the fields will only be populated on access.

Answer (score 1):

i found a way to retrieve the parentid from the child entity by doing a bidirectional mapping of the Parent-child relationship. You can get the ParentId by using a getter method from the child entity that returns the parentId.

Parent Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, length = 10)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int Id;

@Column(name = "Name")
public String name;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();


public Parent() {
}

//getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

//Child Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
public class Child implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int Id;

@Column(name = "Name")
private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "parentId", nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Parent parent;

public Child() {
}

public int getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    Id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@JsonIgnore
public Parent getParent() {
    return parent;
}

//getter method to retrieve the parent id in the child entity
public int getParent_Id(){
    return parent.getId();
}

public void setParent(Parent parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }
}
```

Notice the method **getParent_Id()** which returns the parent Id, since getter methods are used to return object, the parentId would be returned as part of the child entity anytime it is fetched.
Also note the use of **@JsonIgnore** on the **getParent()** method, this to  avoid an infinite recursion going on during serialization since Parent refers to Child and Child refer to Parent.

Comment: You saved me hours man! Other tutorials didn't mention the @JsoIgnore. I was aware about the infinite recursion from years back but I haven't worked on JPA for a while. Also saw your article, thanks for this! https://medium.com/skillhive/how-to-retrieve-a-parent-field-from-a-child-entity-in-a-one-to-many-bidirectional-jpa-relationship-4b3cd707bfb7

Comment: Glad my response was of help to you.